# Importing Data from Outlook 2010 into Excel 2010

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I have form on my website which gets emailed when the customer completes it, then looks like this:-

```
You got mail from  Mr Kelley McIntyre.

Here is the form data:
First Name   : Mr XXXXX
Last Name    : XXXXXX
Company Name     : Army
Email Address    : XXXX@hotmail.co.uk
Telephone/Mobile No      : 0123456789
Date of Event    : 14/12/2013
Number of Guests     : 80
Budget   : 6500-7000
Type of Event    : Other
Catering Required    : Yes
Drinks and Entertainment Requirements    : christmas meal, welcome drink, wine at table

British Army Warrant Officers & Sergeants plus wives and partners
How Did You Hear About Us?   : Google
```

As you can see its fairly simple form, however I need to export this data into Excel every time I get one of these emails, so I can keep a record of all the enquiries we get.

Can someone help?
I know how to do a Macro, but if its VBA, then I'm lost, so its needs to be in idiot format if possible!

Comment: Rossy, you need to show some kind of efforts before you ask a question :) Else I doubt you will receive any help...

Comment: If I knew where to start then I would!

Comment: Perhaps a good VBA Book or Online VBA tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with writing a macro to process an mail item. And setup Outlook Rule to pickup this type of email from Subject/Account then run the macro. Change sExcelFile, sRecordSheet, iC as you see fit. I have made assumptions.

This Code below is for Outlook, please note you need a running Outlook all the time to have this automation. It should get you started half way. Note you need "Microsoft Excel x.0 Object Library" in your References.

```
Public Sub Rules_WebSiteFormRecord(oMail As MailItem)

    Const sExcelFile As String = "C:\Test\Record.xlsx"
    Const sRecordSheet As String = "Record" ' Worksheet name

    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application, oWB As Excel.Workbook, oWS As Excel.worksheet
    Dim arrTxt As Variant, oLine As Variant, iR As Long, iC As Long, bWrite As Boolean

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sExcelFile)
    Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(sRecordSheet)
    ' Make Excel visible for Debug purpose:
    oExcel.Visible = True
    ' Find next row of Last used row in Excel worksheet
    iR = oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' Process email body and store it into columns of worksheet "sRecordSheet"
    'Debug.Print oMail.Body
    ' Store received time of email in Column A
    oWS.Cells(iR, 1).Value = oMail.ReceivedTime
    ' Split the email body into lines then process each
    arrTxt = Split(oMail.Body, vbCrLf)
    For Each oLine In arrTxt
        bWrite = False
        ' store data according to text in line
        If InStr(1, oLine, "First Name", vbTextCompare) Then
            iC = 2 ' Column of First Name
            bWrite = True
        ElseIf InStr(1, oLine, "Last Name", vbTextCompare) Then
            iC = 3 ' Column of First Name
            bWrite = True
            ' Add the rest of the fields...
        End If
        If bWrite Then
            oWS.Cells(iR, iC).Value = Split(oLine, ":")(1)
            iR = iR + 1
        End If
    Next
    Set oWS = Nothing
    ' Close the workbook with saving changes
    oWB.Close True
    Set oWB = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    ' mark it as Read if no error occurred
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        oMail.UnRead = False
    Else
        MsgBox "ERR(" & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description & ") while processing " & oMail.Subject
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```